# Django ORM cache

Tags: django, caching, orm

I have several models with one-to-many relationships.
In my management commands I need to iterate over all entities multiple times. I.e. I have multiple loops like this:

```
for childEntity in dbObj.childEntities.all():
    ....
```

Does Django use session cache for `dbObj.childEntities.all()`? Or I need to cache results somehow?

Answer (score 1):

No, not by default. You can enable it by using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).